# Gold charts on different currencies

Tags: financial-economics, financial-markets, price, pricing, commodities

I have this two charts of gold prices for the last 60 days. One is in Dollars and the other in Euros. Why they are not an exact match?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't double post in different communities - you asked the exact same question on Quant.SE: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/37783. There it was closed for being too basic but with a comment that answers it.

Comment: @LocalVolatility  Sorry, that was because I found the Quant. SE website first than this one. I've deleted the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are different markets, which trade at different hours, leading to different results. There is also the effect of variations of variations in the USD/EUR rates.